# What is the significance of inner Instructions in a transaction and how do they relate to the instructions?

Tags: transactions, instructions

I have some confusion over the inner instructions in a transaction. Does every transaction have inner instructions? Whats the difference between instructions and the inner instructions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So a single instruction may invoke (via Cross Program Invocation) another program's instruction. And this in turn can do the same to yet another program. The maximum 'depth' of this is 4.

From the primary instruction, a CPI instruction is considered 'inner'.

Comment: Great!! any links or resources ?